# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded. Ajax Request on Click

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to build a filter for a table of data that is collected from the database with an AJAX request (in Wordpress). There are 2 dropdown menus and a submit button. The problem is when I click on the submit button my browser freezes and I get the error: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
What's causing this?

The code loads the table when the page is loaded (including the dropdown menus and the submit button). Then once it's loaded it loads the 'click submit button' function.

```
<script>
(function($
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var amount = 10; //get amount of results to show per page
        $.post("<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/ajax_table.php", {
            manual_filter: 1,
            //sector_id : '<?php echo $sector_id; ?>', //send the data to the page using this format
            amount : amount //send the data to the page
        }, function(data) {
            // data will hold the output from the script.php
            $("#table").html(data); //update the div with the output

            $("#submit").click(function (){
                var sector = document.getElementById("sector_dropdown");
                var year = document.getElementById("year_dropdown");
                $.post("<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/ajax_table.php", {
                    manual_filter: '1',
                    sector_id: sector,
                    year: year,
                    amount : amount //send the data to the page using this format
                }, function(data) {
                    // data will hold the output from the script.php
                    $("#table").html(data); //update the div with the output
                });
            });

        });

    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
<div id="table">
</div>
```

Comment: What is `data` ? Does `$("#table").html(data);` add `#submit` element to document ?

Comment: Yes, #submit is loaded into the document with `$("#table").html(data);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it in the end. It wasn't to do with the #submit button, it was to do with the dropdown menu.
This is what got it to work:

```
var sectorALL = document.getElementById("sector_dropdown");
var sector = sectorALL.options[sectorALL.selectedIndex].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is when I click on the submit button my browser freezes
>   and I get the error: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
>   What's causing this?

`$("#table").html(data);` loads duplicate elements having `id` `#submit` ? When `#submit` clicked, all duplicate `#submit` elements `click` handlers called ? Results in adding more duplicate `#submit` elements with `click` events attached , calling `click` handlers of all duplicate `#submit` elements .

---

Note, `id`s should be unique within `document` .

`click` event could be delegated to single handler attached to `#submit` parent element `table` outside of `$.post()` complete callback.

Comment: But there isn't any other element with the id 'submit'

Comment: Can create jsfiddle to demonstrate ?

Comment: I'm not sure I can because of the external resources that my code uses.

Comment: @user5331188 jsfiddle allows users to create a response that will be `echo`ed from the same page http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html ; see also http://plnkr.co . The jsfiddle can be updated by clicking "update" . A draft template which can be updated to reproduce process described at OP https://jsfiddle.net/76bpj7hs/1